# How to access text inside nested div using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying for a long time to access the content of a div by click it.

The structure is like this:

```
<div class="note" id="DYNAMIC_ID">
     <div class="headline">HEADLINE</div>
     <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

I need something like this:

```
$(".note").click(function(){
    alert(this+".headline").text();
    alert(this+".content").text();
});
```

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of your selector is the context. In this case, we want the context to be the div that had been clicked, so we use the `this` keyword as the context.

```
$("div.note").click(function(){
  var headline = $(".headline", this).text();
  alert(headline);
});
```

You could also use the `.find()` method too:

```
var headline = $(this).find(".headline").text();
```

Comment: You're welcome, Bernhard. You can accept the answer by clicking the check-mark to the left of my response.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this could be a solution:

```
$(".note").click(function(){
alert(".headline").html();
alert(".content").html();
```

});

or

```
$(".note").click(function(){
alert("#DYNAMIC_ID").html();
```

});

Comment: This is all wrong. `Alert` doesn't have an .html() method. I think you meant to have that attached to the selector, of which most of your syntax is missing. The selector doesn't go directly inside the alert command - you're missing the jQuery reference, and there's no context to which .headline you're desiring.